# SQL Server: How to retrieve all record based on recent datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

First off, apologies if this has been asked elsewhere as I was unable to find any solution. The best I get is retrieving latest 1 record or 2-3 records. I'm more in search of all records (the number could be dynamic, could be 1 or 2 or maybe 50+) based on recent **Datetime** value. Well so basically here is the problem,

I have a table as follows,

| APILoadDatetime | RowId | ProjectId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 1 | Proj-1 | 101 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 2 | Proj-2 | 81 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 3 | Proj-3 | 111 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 4 | Proj-4 | 125 |
| 2021-05-05 04:46:07.913 | 1 | Proj-1 | 99 |
| 2021-05-05 04:46:07.913 | 2 | Proj-2 | 69 |
| 2021-05-05 04:46:07.913 | 3 | Proj-3 | 105 |
| 2021-05-05 04:46:07.913 | 4 | Proj-4 | 115 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I am looking to do is, write up a query which will give me all the recent data based on Datetime, so in this case, I should get the following result,

| APILoadDatetime | RowId | ProjectId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 1 | Proj-1 | 101 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 2 | Proj-2 | 81 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 3 | Proj-3 | 111 |
| 2021-07-13 15:09:14.620 | 4 | Proj-4 | 125 |

The RowId shows (as the name suggests) gives the number of Rows for a particular **Datetime** block. This will not always be 4, it's dynamic based on the data received so could be 1,2,4 or even 50+ ...

Hope I was able to convey the question properly, Thank you all for reading and Pre-Thank you to those who provide solution to this.

Comment: So you want all rows from the most recent datetime?

Comment: Yes exactly. Bear in mind, that the number of Rows can vary with every Datetime, sometimes can be less and sometimes can be more - What I'm after is to get all Rows from the most recent Datetime the data was received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function `row_number` to find out the latest entry for each projectid:

```
select * from (
   select * , rank() over (order by APILoadDatetime desc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately can't do Partition over ProjectId, as at times, there are unknown Projects which are assigned 'UNKNOWN' to begin with, and these could be numerous at any given Datetime (e.g., 5-6 times), all these need to be selected as well. The SQL above only selects one last occurrence of these ProjectIds missing out on others.

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n so it is solely based on date/time? I'm not following. in your sample data you have projectid

Comment: yes the sample data does have ProjectId in it, but ProjectId is not UNIQUE, not it's PRIMARY KEY, one a single datetime, we can have numerous amount of ProjectIds, consider it more like different machineries hired for Projects, so we can have 6-7 machineries all hired for one Project. Hope it makes any sense now ...

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n then you don’t need to partition. See updated answer

Comment: Awesome @eshirvana, surely very simple ... Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 with ties 
    * 
from 
     tablename
order by 
    row_number() over(
        partition by RowId 
        order by APILoadDatetime desc
    );
```

`TOP 1` works with `WITH TIES` here.

`WITH TIES` means that when `ORDER BY = 1`, then `SELECT` takes this record (because of `TOP 1`) and all others that have `ORDER BY = 1` (because of `WITH TIES`).

**Update #1:**

If you need the last record by `APILoadDatetime` and several records which might have the same `APILoadDatetime` (as the first found), then the query is simplier:

```
select top 1 with ties 
    * 
from 
    tablename
order by 
    APILoadDatetime desc;
```

Comment: Really a good script, however there is one issue. There are occassions when the number of Rows at a particular datetime is higher or lower, like in the data I have, there are occassions when RowID for a date in past have exceeded 4 and is 7, so this script gave me all 4 rows with the latest datetime, but then also gave 3 more rows with the latest datetime for those specific rows. My requirement is to get the only 4 rows I've recently received and none of the ones before that. Thanks

Comment: @rac3b3nn0n please see my `Update #1`.

Comment: Oh awesome @Vadim ... Thanks a lot ... yes this surely is simple, didnt think it would be this simple :) ... Thanks a lot